# How to export SWF from FDT?

Tags: fdt

This is probably the most obvious question on the face of Earth, but I'm an Actionscript newbie.  I'm using the FDT plugin for Eclipse on Mac (FDT version 1.13, eclipse "Kepler Service Release 1" with build ID "20130919-0819", using OS X 10.9.1) to make an Actionscript 3 project.  Everything works perfectly fine, and debugging/running works perfectly.  However, I have no idea how to export it.  Disabling "Build Automatically" then pressing Build All or Build Project seems to do something, it shows a loading bar for a second then it disappears.  I believe I checked something like "Include web files" when I started my project, so that may be the culprit.  Here is the contents of my project:

```
    assets
    -some images that I have
    bin
    -history
    --history.css
    --history.js
    --historyFrame.html
    -index.html {when I open shows the game, but I want an swf}
    -playerProductInstall.swf {shows just a blue screen}
    -swfobject.js {I think this has something to do with it, but I want an swf}
    lib {empty}
    src {I'm not showing you what's in here}
```

Answer (score 0):

Duh!  The files are stored in bin, they just don't show up in the Eclipse/FDT window.  Open the bin folder in Finder and you'll see an swf, get the one with the name of your main class and you're good to go!